# Vue Select selected option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-select

I'm working on a Customer Service ABM. For user search, i'm using Vue Select to filter and select the correct Customer... Vue Select get the customers list from my customers api, then i fetch data into vue select. THe user can filter to get the correct customer...

[image]

[image]

What I need to know is how to assign the selected client when I want to "edit" a service. When a user press on "Service Edit" the modal open in edit mode, it's make an api call to "/service/{id}" to get Service information. The service response with all the service information, and with the customer ID... the problem is that if I put it as defaul selected ...

[image]

Here is my vuejs information:

[image]

My searchCustomers function, to fetch data into "options":

```
searchCustomers(search){

            let searchVal = search.split(' ').join('+');

            axios.get('api/customer?nomina=&filter=' + searchVal)
            .then((response) => {
              this.options = response.data['data'];
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
          },
```

new service modal, to get data from api:

```
newEditServiceModal(id){

            this.editMode = true;

            this.$Progress.start();

            this.service.clear();
            this.service.reset();

            axios.get('api/service/' + id)
            .then((data) => {
              this.service.fill(data.data)
            })
            .catch(() => {
              this.$Progress.fail();
            })

            $('#serviceModal').modal('show');

          },
```

And finally my v-select component:

```
<v-select 
  :options="options" 
  @search="searchCustomers" 
  :filterable="false" 
  v-model="service.id_customers" 
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': service.errors.has('customer.id') }"
>
  <template 
    slot="no-options"
  >
    Buscar un cliente...
  </template>

  <template 
    slot="option" 
    slot-scope="option"
  >
    <div class="d-center">
    {{ option.id + ' - ' + option.name }}
    </div>
  </template>

  <template 
    slot="selected-option" 
    slot-scope="option" 
    :value="option.id" 
    v-model="service.id_customers"
  >
    <div class="selected d-center">
      {{ option.id + ' - ' + option.name }}
    </div>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

**What would be the correct way to pass the id, and assign the correct customer to v-form?**

Comment: I don't understand your need but you must to use map or foreach and display it in options

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the trick. This shows how you can assign the selected value into form fields. For the inputs, the trick is using `v-model` on them.. Examples are below.

---

***Edit:*** updated my answer in order to use `slots`..

---

Does this help answer your question, or am I misunderstanding it?

I would brush up on [their documentation](https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting) if I were you - it is extremely helpful!

---

[[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/eorrdB?editors=1010)]

---

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: "",
    options: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Guido Caffa"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "John Doe"
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest/dist/vue-select.css">

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <v-select v-model="selected" :options="options">
      <template v-slot:option="option">
        {{ option.id }} - {{ option.name }}  
      </template>
      <template v-slot:selected-option="option">
        {{ option.id }} - {{ option.name }}
      </template>
    </v-select>
    <div v-if="selected !== ''" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <hr/> Selected Item:
      <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div v-if="selected !== ''" style="margin-top:20px;">
      Name:
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="selected.name" />
      </div>
      ID:
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="selected.id" />
      </div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```